# Question about hair types

Tags: word-request

Could somebody tell me please that what is the word that you use for a person who lost **most** of his hair?(he is not bald yet)

Comment: The problem is called "hair loss", and a commonly used term for "hair restoration surgery" is "hair transplant". See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_loss.

Comment: @ Damkerng T. Yes.I forgot its name (hair transplant surgery)    Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That person is said to be *balding* or *going bald*.

Answer (score 3):

They are *balding*. Here is the link to *balding* in [Cambridge Dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/balding).

Comment: OK I will remove it.So how can I politely bring up this subjects?

Comment: @Khashayar Do you want to bring them up with somebody who is bald/balding?

Comment: I wanna talk about his hair problems :)

Comment: @Khashayar Btw, *hairy* doesn't mean with hair on your head. It usually refers to hair on a body, or on an object.

Comment: @Khashayar talk to *him* about his hair problems? If so, I would say: don't do it! Unless he brings it up himself. If he does, then that's ok. Unless your bald too. If your bald too then then it doesn't matter :)

Comment: I am not very close to him and by the way, What is wrong with these subjects?

Comment: Some people are very sensitive about the way they look, especially if they are not happy about it. In Britain, we don't usually talk about how heavy, overweight, bald or spotty somebody is. If you don't know them, it might be considered a bit rude, as if you're criticizing them ..

Comment: OK. these subjects are dangerous.You are right :)  Honestly,I was going to purpose him to have hair operation?!(I don't know how do you say it) because my father did.My intention is good

Comment: @Khashayar Well, I suppose you could always talk about your father. If you say he had an operation your friend might ask what kind of operation, then you could tell him perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Balding, as the others say.

Yet there is the subtle shading of 'receding' ie, the hair is disappearing from the front, but there's some still at the back.

Which would lead to variations on how people try to hide that fact...

*Comb-over* - taking long hair from one side & combing it over the 'shiny bits', which nearly works unless it's windy [Google 'Bobby Charlton']
Known, as I understand it, in Japanese as a '*bar-code*', from the similarity to the identifying marks on the side of any grocery product you scan through a till in the supermarket.

The alternative 'cure' - whilst not really fixing it - is to shave it all off.... Known as a '*Jean-Luc Picard*' or just '*Picard*', after the Captain of the USS Enterprise, Star Trek, the next generation.